# Techniques to measure application performance

Tags: performance, concurrency, max

I maintain an application which, during the course of two years, has constantly required new hardware to be even usable, due to the amount of new users / new data inserted. However, justifying the investiment is sometimes very hard to do.

I started to wonder - how can I establish the maximum number of users a web application currently suports?

I thought of using JMeter scripts but they can get really nasty to implement when having to simulate file transfers and decison trees. What do you guys use?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146092/what-are-the-best-resources-to-learn-about-capacity-planning#152908

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this performance algorithm:

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/cc500561.fig02_L(en-us).gif

> **R** Response time. The total time from the user requesting a page
> (by clicking a link, and so on) to when the full page is rendered on
> the user's computer. Typically measured in seconds. Payload   Total
> bytes sent to the browser, including markup and all resources (such as
> CSS, JS, and image files).
>
> **Bandwidth** Rate of transfer to and from the browser. This may be
> asymmetrical and might represent multiple speeds if a given page is
> generated from multiple sources. Usually, it is averaged together to
> create a single bandwidth expressed in bytes per second.
>
> **AppTurns**  The number of resource files a given page needs. These
> resource files will include CSS, JS, images, and any other files
> retrieved by the browser in the process of rendering the page. In the
> equation, the HTML page is accounted for separately by adding in
> round-trip time (RTT) before the AppTurns expression.
>
> **RTT**   The time it takes to round-trip, regardless of bytes
> transferred. Every request pays a minimum of one RTT for the page
> itself. Typically measured in milliseconds.
>
> **Concurrent Requests**   Number
> of simultaneous requests a browser will make for resource files. By
> default, Internet Explorer performs two concurrent requests. This
> setting can be adjusted but rarely is.
>
> **Cs**    Compute time on the server. This is the time it takes for code
> to run, retrieve data from the database, and compose the response to
> be sent to the browser. Measured in milliseconds.
>
> **Cc**    Compute time on the client. This is the time it takes for a
> browser to actually render the HTML on the screen, execute JavaScript,
> implement CSS rules, and so on.

For more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500561.aspx

Answer (score 1):

We use HP's [LoadRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LoadRunner).  But it's not cheap, and you still have to create scripts, test cases.

Comment: Even if expensive, does the value of the offering outweigh the cost?  If so, then even an expensive piece of software, equipment, car, flight, etc... can be worth every penny paid.  If the Value does not outweigh the cost then its time to revisit the tool being used.